# Making a background image stay with jquery.cookie.js

Tags: jquery, cookies, slider

At this moment I have a background image slider, where the user can click on a button and choose one of seven images to have as the background while they are viewing the site, the issue of course is that when they click threw to a different page it reverts back to the default image. Is there a way I can get jquery.cookie.js to solve this problem? The following is my attempt.

The jQuery part that works:

```
            $(function(){
                $('.btn a').parents('.btn').click(function(){
                    var img = $(this).attr('data-bg-img'),
                    afterFadeIn = function() {
                        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')');
                        $('bg-style').css('opacity', 0);
                    };
                    $('#bg-style')
                    .css({'background-image': 'url(' + img + ')', 'opacity': 0})
                    .animate({ 'opacity' : 1 }, 500, afterFadeIn);
                });
            });
```

The jQuery part that doesn't:
                $(function() {

```
                if($.cookie("html_img")) {
                    $('html').css("background-image", $.cookie("html_img"));
                }

                $('.btn a').click(function() {

                    var image = 'imgs/someimage.jpg';
                    // var image = $(this).attr('src');

                    $('html').css("background-image", image);

                    $.cookie("html_img", image, {expires:7});

                    return false;

                });

            });
```

The HTML:

```
            <div id="slideshow" class="bgSlider">
                <div class="btn btn1" data-bg-img ="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/k2-in-skies.jpg"><a href="#">Button 1</a></div>
                <div class="btn btn2" data-bg-img ="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/k2.jpg" class="bgimage"><a href="#">Button 2</a></div>
                <div class="btn btn3" data-bg-img ="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/kunhar-river.jpg"><a href="#">Button 3</a></div>
                <div class="btn btn4" data-bg-img ="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/mitre-peak-baltoro.jpg"><a href="#">Button 4</a></div>
                <div class="btn btn5" data-bg-img ="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/musa-ka-musalla.jpg"><a href="#">Button 5</a></div>
                <div class="btn btn6" data-bg-img ="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/nanga-parbat.jpg"><a href="#">Button 6</a></div>
                <div class="btn btn7" data-bg-img ="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/naran-valley.jpg"><a href="#">Button 7</a></div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
```

The CSS:

```
             #bg-style { width:100%; height: 700px; position:absolute; }

            .btncontain { width:80%; margin: 0 auto; position:absolute; }

            .btn a { width: 150px; height: 70px; background: yellow; float: left; margin: 0 30px 100px 30px; }

            #bg-style {
                background: url(../images/k2-in-skies.jpg) no-repeat center top;
            }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you give us more details about why that doesn't work? What do you see? Can you step into it with breakpoints in your browser's developer tools? What do you see?

Comment: Thanks Rup, I'm afraid i don't know how to set up breakpoints (yet) but looking at it in Chromes Console it doesn't come back with any errors, so I'm not sure what's going on with it?

Comment: In Chrome's developer tools go to the script tab, find this code then left-click on the line number inside the function you want to stop in.

Answer (score 0):

That's handy I put in a breakpoint at the first line of the cookie code and I got this back?

```
            function (key, value, options) {

                    // key and at least value given, set cookie...
                    if (arguments.length > 1 && (!/Object/.test(Object.prototype.toString.call(value)) || value === null || value === undefined)) {
                        options = $.extend({}, options);

                        if (value === null || value === undefined) {
                            options.expires = -1;
                        }

                        if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                            var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
                            t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
                        }

                        value = String(value);

                        return (document.cookie = [
                            encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
                            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
                            options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
                            options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
                            options.secure ? '; secure' : ''
                        ].join(''));
                    }

                    // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
                    options = value || {};
                    var decode = options.raw ? function(s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent;

                    var pairs = document.cookie.split('; ');
                    for (var i = 0, pair; pair = pairs[i] && pairs[i].split('='); i++) {
                        if (decode(pair[0]) === key) return decode(pair[1] || ''); // IE saves cookies with empty string as "c; ", e.g. without "=" as opposed to EOMB, thus pair[1] may be undefined
                    }
                    return null;
                }
```

Comment: Right - that's the [jQuery cookie function](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js). Can you step through it in your code and inspect the variables to see what's going on, and where it's going wrong?

Comment: well if I hover my mouse over $.cookie this line `if($.cookie("html_img")) {` I get "undefined" which I take means it's not sinking up to to the cookie script?